# MouseEnter/MouseLeave event's not queuing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a drop-down animation on a navigation where sub-menu's show/hide depending on user hovering in/out of the element. The issue I'm having is that these are not queuing up correctly so when a user quickly passes over the element, the menu stays open.

I've tried using the .stop(true) function chained onto the animation but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

```
$('.navbar-nav > .menu-item-has-children').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            console.log('Hovered In');
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').addClass('main-fix').stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: 'up', duration: 250, easing: 'easeInQuint'}).removeClass('main-fix');
        },
        mouseleave:  function() {
            console.log('Hovered Out');
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').addClass('main-fix').stop(true, true).hide('slide', {direction: 'up', duration: 250, easing: 'easeInQuint'}).removeClass('main-fix');
        }
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h3qacoez/1/

Comment: You have a `duration:250` on the `mouseleave` event, causing the menu item hide transition to animate. If you change to `duration:0` it will hide instantly. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody that is not what OP means.

Comment: The issue is with your show() and hide(). If you swap it to slideDown and slideUp the code works fine.

Comment: I added jQuery UI tag has it seems related with the  jQuery UI animation methods and jQuery fx queue

Comment: @epascarello - I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Hi Brett, try moving the mouse in and out as quickly as possible on the "Albums" menu option from the fiddle I provided. The submenu stays open, as opposed to closing after mouseLeave.

Comment: If you change your `show(...)` to `slideDown()` and `hide(...)` to `slideUp()` it seems to work fine. Not sure why.

Comment: epascarello your suggestion ALMOST did it. It definitely works for menus that open from top to bottom (which is what I showed here). However, the actual menu I'm working on has both submenus that open from top to bottom and left to right (for which this solution doesn't work). Since I didn't recreate that in the example I provided, does that mean I should mark your suggestion as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS and `:hover` for this? Transitions in CSS will allow you to animate the element as well. Unless you have requirements to support old browsers this should work nicely and save you any JavaScript headaches and timing issues.

For completeness here is a Fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/q0tfxvwd/

The relevant parts of the CSS is:

```
#navbar .navbar-nav .menu-item .sub-menu {
  ...
  /* no display: none! */
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-transition: max-height 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#navbar .navbar-nav .menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Where the first part sets up the normal state and the second is during hover. Max-height is used instead of height as it will allow the sub-menu to be any height (just make sure max.height is in pixels and large enough to accommodate any submenu).

## Why?

It's not constructive to help someone fix a problem at any cost. Sometimes it's worth it to rethink the approach.

Using JS for menu animation certainly works. But does it add anything to the approach above? With CSS you offload rendering to the graphics card, use the browsers built in hover detection and progress your code towards the new web standards.

Unless you have very special needs, such as a client willing to pay for pixel perfect results across legacy clients or very complex animations depending on external events for timing etc, it's generally not worth building these animations in JS. And if you'r not getting payed to make it all the same all the time you should not do it ...